# Не могу понять работу кода

Tags: java

Почему результатом работы программы становится значение -128? если делать вывод на экран после каждой итерации цикла, то значения растут от 1 до 127, а на выходе из цикла получается -128.

```
public class Test {    
public static void main(String[] args) {
   byte b = 0;
   while (++b > 0) {System.out.println(b);};
   System.out.println("final b = " + b); }}
```

Comment: В байте кончились положительные числа. Какое значение Вы ожидали?

Comment: Любое другое) Получается, когда у него кончаются положительные числа, он просто заново начнет их увеличивать и так до бесконечности?

Comment: Считайте, что 256 значений байта располагаются по кругу.

Comment: Прикольно ОО Спасибо за ответ :з

Answer (score 4, accepted):

После 127 происходит [целочисленное переполнение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Для любого целочисленного типа в Java верно, что `(максимальное значение + 1) = минимальное значение`. Это свойство представления чисел в Java ( [Дополнительный код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)), которое определено спецификацией ([JLS §4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2)):

> The integral types are byte, short, int, and long, whose values are 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit **signed two's-complement integers**, ...

Для демонстрации следующий код напечатает `true` четыре раза:

```
System.out.println((byte) (Byte.MAX_VALUE + 1) == Byte.MIN_VALUE);
System.out.println((short) (Short.MAX_VALUE + 1) == Short.MIN_VALUE);
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE);
System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE + 1 == Long.MIN_VALUE);
```

Явное приведение типа для `byte` и `short` вызвано тем, что операции сложения для этих типов возвращает `int`.